# Sending mass email campaign via ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, smtp, sendmail

I have read a few other posts on here about mass emailing, but I need some other information. We want to integrate our mass e-mail system into our current application, but I fear this may not be a good idea. Does anyone have any input as to what kind of resources are needed to send, potentially, 1000's of emails an hour? We only have one web server right now and do not have access to our mail server. We do have full access to our web server, however. Would it be a bad idea to host the mass e-mail application on our current  server? Should we have a separate sever to run this type of application and call the server via web services (WCF)? Each email would need to be sent separately because the links on the e-mail are for tracking and unsubscribing purposes. I appreciate your thoughts.
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

Yes its a bad idea,

One of the key things for detecting spam, is the IP address it came from (Known as its reputation) if you start sending out alot of emails which end up getting marked as spam (Which is likly, even if the users said they wated to recieve email) your IP address could end up in trouble. I wouldnt fancy doing this on my webserver.

As for specs, your bandwidth is going to be hit hard when you start doing somthing like this. Although I think you would be suprised at how fast you can send out emails (Mail Server Dependant)

Either way when it comes to sending mass mail campaigns out, I'd speak to a third party if its somthing you are serious about, they have the knowledge and hardware to perform campaigns that are not going to damage your IP rep.

Comment: Also who hosts your server? I'd check with them they might not like the idea of you hogging resource while shipping out 1000's of emails.

Comment: The email server is a separate system desgined for mass emails. We are allowed 500,000 emails a week. I am not concerend about bandwidth considering all of the traffic is internal to our host's netowork and the email server takes care of sending out the emails (which we are not resposible for any bandwidth at that point). My main concern is the application generating the emails to send to the server (in the same network). As for the reputation, this is also convered by the mail server.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue all depends on your mail server. I've been in a project where we sent out 50-100K emails in a few hours and the main limitation was the capacity of the mail server. In my opinion it would be fine to have the mail client run on the web server as it won't be using too much resources if well written, the main question is what the mail server can take.

Comment: Take the IP reoutation into account though as stated in the other answer, I have limited knowledge of this are but would not mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can help your reputation on some email providers by contacting them and or filling out bulk mail registrations.

This is for yahoo:

http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/bulkv2.html

I would not recommend using exchange for anything like this.  You will want a separate bulk mail server like Ironport.

http://www.ironport.com/

Otherwise your internal emails will get stuck in the queue with all of your bulk emails which you definitely don't want.

The actual code involved does not have to be that complex.  In my case we used an asynchronous task to loop over an email list table in the DB pulling out a batch of 20 or so at a time sending then sleeping for a number of seconds.  Email providers do not like receiving hundreds/thousands of emails from a source at one time.  Even better if you can stagger the list by providers.

Comment: The bulk mail system is a separate server form our internal mail.